# How to get TestNG method to terminate as soon as time-out is reached?

Tags: java, testng

I have to write tests for a website that sometimes hangs indefinitely while loading a page. I'd like to write a method that times out 20 minutes after it starts running.

But when I try to write code like this -

```java
@Test(timeOut=4000)
public void test() {
    try { Thread.sleep(5000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println("I don't want this to print.");
}
```

The test prints "I don't want this to print." and THEN fails with the intended exception - `org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException: Method didn't finish within the time-out 4000`

How can I get the test to fail as soon as the time limit is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;**
Do not catch `InterruptedException` just put in throws clause.

As TestNG works (in this case) the framework will create a new *single-threaded* executorService, submit a worker which will be waiting for termination. If the test running was not finished the worker will throw `org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException`.
Related source code is:

**org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper**

```java
  private static void invokeWithTimeoutWithNewExecutor(
      ITestNGMethod tm,
      Object instance,
      Object[] parameterValues,
      ITestResult testResult,
      IHookable hookable)
      throws InterruptedException, ThreadExecutionException {
    ExecutorService exec = ThreadUtil.createExecutor(1, tm.getMethodName());

    InvokeMethodRunnable imr =
        new InvokeMethodRunnable(tm, instance, parameterValues, hookable, testResult);
    Future<Void> future = exec.submit(imr);
    exec.shutdown();
    long realTimeOut = MethodHelper.calculateTimeOut(tm);
    boolean finished = exec.awaitTermination(realTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    if (!finished) {
      exec.shutdownNow();
      ThreadTimeoutException exception =
          new ThreadTimeoutException(
              "Method "
                  + tm.getQualifiedName()
                  + "() didn't finish within the time-out "
                  + realTimeOut);
      testResult.setThrowable(exception);
      testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
    } else {
      Utils.log(
          "Invoker " + Thread.currentThread().hashCode(),
          3,
          "Method " + tm.getMethodName() + " completed within the time-out " + tm.getTimeOut());

      // We don't need the result from the future but invoking get() on it
      // will trigger the exception that was thrown, if any
      try {
        future.get();
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw new ThreadExecutionException(e.getCause());
      }

      testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS); // if no exception till here then SUCCESS.
    }
  }
```

The point is:

```java
ExecutorService exec = ThreadUtil.createExecutor(1, tm.getMethodName());
// ... and
boolean finished = exec.awaitTermination(realTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.awaitTermination(...)` method throws `InterruptedException` which was handled in the test method. Because of this the test method won't be terminated but the `finished` flag will be false.

So it will help:

```java
@Test(timeOut = 4000)
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("I don't want this to print");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the source code deep-dive. While this example was solved by throwing the exception, it turned out my issue was because of the version of TestNG I was using - https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2009 . Updating TestNG fixed my problem.